# converting new line character

Tags: c

I am trying to convert new line character  \n to dos style which is \r\n , without using libc.

here is my attempt, what am I doing wrong?

```
       for(i = 0; str[i]!='\0'; ++i)
{
   if ('\r' == str[i] && '\n'==str[i+1]) 
       ++count;
}

strPtr = malloc(i + 1 + count);

for(i = j = 0; str[i]!='\0'; ++i)
{
   if ('\r' == str[i]) 
   strPtr[j++] = "";
}

strPtr[j] = 0;
```

output should now be
"Hi\r\n, How are you \r\n, are you okay\r\n"

Comment: `\n` is escape sequence for a single character with ASCII code 10. It is not stored as 2 character ``\`` and `n`.

Comment: it is. when you use a single character, it does not parse it properly. That did not solve my problem.

Comment: Open the compiled binary in a HEX editor, you will see that there is no `\n` sequence, but instead a single character with value 0xA (10)

Answer (score 4):

There are many problems here.  Firstly, you are modifying the string *in place* using the original buffer.  However, the original buffer does not have enough space to store the additional `\r` characters.  You'll need to allocate a larger buffer.

Secondly, a UNIX-style carriage return character is not stored as two separate `\` and `n` characters.  It is a single ASCII character with a value of `0xA`, which can be represented using the escape sequence `\n`.  So to check if your current character is a newline character, you want to say `strPtr[i] == '\n'`

Finally, you are *overwriting* the old buffer when you say `strPtr[i-1] = '\r'`.  This will replace the character *before* the `\n`, (such as the `i` in `Hi`).

Basically, what you want to do is create a second buffer for output, and copy the string character by character to the output buffer.  When you encounter a `\n` character, instead of copying a single `\n` to the new buffer, you copy `\r\n`.

The size of the output buffer needs to be twice the size of the input buffer to handle the case of an input string where every character is `\n`, plus 1 for the NULL terminator.  However, you can compute an optimal size for the output buffer by counting the number of `\n` characters in the original string beforehand.

Comment: is \r\n also all 1 char like a \n?

Comment: No, `\r\n` is actually 2 chars, thus resulting in endless misery and suffering since the early 80s.

Answer (score 1):

All the escape sequence characters in C language are one character which is stored in one byte of memory only, dont consider it as two.

So you can directly check for a byte to `\n` as you are checking for `\0`.

If you want to replace `\n`(1 character) with `\r\n`(2 character) means, `str` should have additional memory, but in your program its not having additional memory.

```
char *a = "\n"; //This is one byte
char *b = "\\\n"; //This is two byte, 1st byte for '\' and 2nd byte for new line
char *c = "\\\r\n"; //Similarly this is three byte
char *c = "\r\n"; //Similarly this is two byte
```

All the below escape sequence characters are single byte character in C language.

```
\n – New line
\r – Carriage return
\t – Horizontal tab
\\ – Backslash
\' – Single quotation mark
\" – Double quotation mark
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in-place. You're adding a new character ('\r') for every '\n' which means the string must expand.  The worst case scenario is that every character is a '\n' which means we would double the size of the string. Thus, let's make a buffer twice the size of the original string.

```
strtmp = malloc(strlen(str) * 2 + 1); /* +1 for null */
strcpy(strtmp, str);
strptr = strtmp;

for (i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++)
{
    if ((str[i] == '\\') && (str[i+1] == 'n'))
    {
        *strptr++ = '\\';
        *strptr++ = 'r';
    }

    *strptr++ = str[i];
}

printf(strtmp);
free(strtmp);
```

Comment: Rather wasteful of memory (esp if string is long) by doubling the length.

Comment: If you want to be memory thrifty, then scan and count the number of new-lines so you know how much to expand string. If time is worse then a bit of memory, then my way is better. Trade offs...

Comment: @PQuinn is strtmp a char array? can you provide the variable declarations

Comment: I am getting an error saying incompatible types at the malloc line int main(int argc, char**argv) {
char* strtmp;    
char str[] = "Hi\n, How are you \n, are you okay\n";
char *strptr;

strtmp = malloc(strlen(str) * 2 + 1); /* +1 for null */
strcpy(strtmp, str);
strptr = strtmp;
int i =0;
for (i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++)
{
    if ((str[i] == '\\') && (str[i+1] == 'n'))
    {
        *strptr++ = '\\';
        *strptr++ = 'r';
    }

    *strptr++ = str[i];
}

printf(strtmp);
free(strtmp);
    
    return 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

The `\n` in your string is an escape sequence and is represented by one character.

Your code should be like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "Hi\n, How are you \n, are you okay\n";
    char *strPtr = str;

    int i, j;
    int count=0;

    for(i = 0; str[i]!='\0'; ++i)
    {
       if (`\n` == str[i]) ++count;
    }
    strPtr = malloc(i + 1 + count);
    for(i = j = 0; str[i]!='\0'; ++i)
    {
       if ('\n' == str[i]) strPtr[j++] = `\r`;
       strPtr[j++] = str[i];
    }
    strPtr[j] = 0;

    printf("This many times we changed it", count);
}
```

**EDIT**

As you have decided to change the question (BTW - Just add to the question for clarification and not delete huge chunks of the original OP as the answers will not make any sense for future visitors) - here is the code:

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "Hi\r\n, How are you \r\n, are you okay\r\n";

    int i, j;
    for (i = j = 0; 0 != str[i]; ++i)
    {
       if ('\r' == str[i] && '\n' == str[i + 1])
       {
          ++count;
       }
       else
       {
          str[j++] = str[i];
       }
    }
    str[j] = 0;

    .. etc - str is without \r\n but \n, count is the number of lines.
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need a larger buffer? to store the extra char? suppose its 10 lines with 10 '\n' wouldn't this result in an error?

Comment: @user1888502 - The `malloc` creates the buffer of the correct length. `i = strlen(str)` after the for loop, `count` is the number of '\n' characters, the 1 is for the null character. `strPtr` is the new string with the extra '\r' in it

Comment: what is this line doing? its raising an erorr        strPtr[j++] ] str[i];

Comment: That was a typo that I have fixed.

Comment: What does that strPtr[j]=0 do at the end? I am learning a lot.

Comment: @ Ed Heal, I wrote code that does the reverse, why doesn't it work? look at my updated post.

Comment: I want to omit the \r and just have the \n

Comment: So why did you write "I am trying to convert new line character \n to dos style which is \r\n" - the first line in the question?!

Comment: @user1888502 - Counts the number of new lines. Do you require that value? If not remove the line followed by the else. Use de-morgans law of the if statement.